# How to add a banner adview to the layout?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm pretty sure that Google used to publish an XML snippet of how to add a banner AdView to the layout, a ConstraintLayout to be precise. But that isn't in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) anymore.

There is a section called **Add AdView to the layout** and it contains a code snipped with some weird screen size calculations without any explanations of why I have to do this. I haven't seen this before. Is this supposed to integrate with *Compose* somehow? If so, how?

However, I'm on a good old XML layout. How to integrate an AdView in an XML layout in 2024?